# OpenJPA2 rollbacks 'Create entity' transactions after a few days the server starts

Tags: jpa, ejb, rollback, openjpa

I have a simple web app with JPA2 (OpenJPA2).

I start the server (TomEE+ 1.7.4 on a Ubuntu Server 12.04 in a VPS). The app starts to work and does service. After a few days running, in a CRUD view of a certain entity, when trying to create an entity instance, the Persistence engine rollsbacks transactions for creating entity instance. And an exception report appears in the browser client.

> javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: Transaction was rolled back, presumably because setRollbackOnly was called during a synchronization

Tried many things, don't want to annoy you guys here, but I really don't know what to do!

If I shutdown TomEE and start it back. Problem dissapears and the entities are created and stored flawlessly by the EntityManager.

DB engine is MySQL. Project uses Maven. Most dependencies are 'provided'.

Following are involved files:
persistence config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="AEEA-PU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>
    <jta-data-source>AEEA-JNDI2</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <shared-cache-mode>ALL</shared-cache-mode>
    <properties>
      <property name="openjpa.jdbc.SynchronizeMappings" value="buildSchema(ForeignKeys=true)"/>
      <property name="openjpa.jdbc.DBDictionary" value="org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.MySQLDictionary"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

The Entity class: (getters and setters omitted)

```
@Entity
public class Ubicacion implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String descripcion;
    private String salon;
    private String horarios;
    private String domicilio;
    private String ciudad;
    private String telefonos;
    @Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date fechaHoraAlta;
    private String comentarios;
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Usuario usuarioAlta;

    private String urlMaps;
```

The abstract facade:

```
import java.util.List; import javax.persistence.EntityManager;


public abstract class AbstractFacade<T> {
    private Class<T> entityClass;

    public AbstractFacade(Class<T> entityClass) {
        this.entityClass = entityClass;
    }

    protected abstract EntityManager getEntityManager();

    public void create(T entity) {
        getEntityManager().persist(entity);
    } //...
```

the concrete facade:

```
@Stateless
public class UbicacionFacade extends AbstractFacade<Ubicacion> {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "AEEA-PU")
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return em;
    }
```

and for last, the managed bean with its method

> public String ubicacionNueva()

, that is called from a primefaces p:commandButton for creating the entity and store it. The method takes the temporary Entity in the managed bean, sets up a couple properties like logged user and date of creation, and calls the facade for storing the entity in the database.

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class UbicacionesBacking{

    @EJB
    private UbicacionFacade ubicacionFacade;

    private Ubicacion tmpUbi;


    public UbicacionesBacking() {
    }

    public String ubicacionNueva() {

        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        LoginBacking bean = context.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(context, "#{loginBacking}", LoginBacking.class);

        this.tmpUbi.setUsuarioAlta(bean.getCurrentUser());
        this.tmpUbi.setFechaHoraAlta(new Date());

        ubicacionFacade.create(this.tmpUbi);

        this.tmpUbi = new Ubicacion();

        return "ubicacionLista";
    }
```

following is the exception report

> Estado HTTP 500 - javax.el.ELException:
>   javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: Transaction was rolled
>   back, presumably because setRollbackOnly was called during a
>   synchronization
>
> type Informe de Excepción
>
> mensaje javax.el.ELException:
>   javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: Transaction was rolled
>   back, presumably because setRollbackOnly was called during a
>   synchronization
>
> descripción El servidor encontró un error interno que hizo que no
>   pudiera rellenar este requerimiento.
>
> excepción
>
> javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.el.ELException:
>   javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: Transaction was rolled
>   back, presumably because setRollbackOnly was called during a
>   synchronization
>     javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:230)
>     org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:100)
>
> causa raíz
>
> org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.el.ContextAwareELException:
>   javax.el.ELException: javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException:
>   Transaction was rolled back, presumably because setRollbackOnly was
>   called during a synchronization
>     org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.el.ContextAwareTagMethodExpression.invoke(ContextAwareTagMethodExpression.java:108)
>     org.apache.myfaces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:74)
>     javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:120)
>     javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot._broadcastAll(UIViewRoot.java:1172)
>     javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:365)
>     javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot._process(UIViewRoot.java:1658)
>     javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:862)
>     org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationExecutor.execute(InvokeApplicationExecutor.java:42)
>     org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:196)
>     org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:143)
>     javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:198)
>     org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:100)
>
> causa raíz
>
> javax.el.ELException: javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException:
>   Transaction was rolled back, presumably because setRollbackOnly was
>   called during a synchronization
>     org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:292)
>     org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:273)
>     org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.el.ContextAwareTagMethodExpression.invoke(ContextAwareTagMethodExpression.java:96)
>     org.apache.myfaces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:74)
>     javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:120)
>     javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot._broadcastAll(UIViewRoot.java:1172)
>     javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:365)
>     javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot._process(UIViewRoot.java:1658)
>     javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:862)
>     org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationExecutor.execute(InvokeApplicationExecutor.java:42)
>     org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:196)
>     org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:143)
>     javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:198)
>     org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:100)
>
> causa raíz
>
> javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: Transaction was rolled
>   back, presumably because setRollbackOnly was called during a
>   synchronization
>     org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.BaseEjbProxyHandler.convertException(BaseEjbProxyHandler.java:400)
>     org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.BaseEjbProxyHandler.invoke(BaseEjbProxyHandler.java:329)
>     fachadas.UbicacionFacade$$LocalBeanProxy.agregarUbicacion(fachadas/UbicacionFacade.java)
>     porotosAdministrados.UbicacionesBacking.ubicacionNueva(UbicacionesBacking.java:38)
>     sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>     sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
>     org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:279)
>     org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:273)
>     org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.el.ContextAwareTagMethodExpression.invoke(ContextAwareTagMethodExpression.java:96)
>     org.apache.myfaces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:74)
>     javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:120)
>     javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot._broadcastAll(UIViewRoot.java:1172)
>     javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:365)
>     javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot._process(UIViewRoot.java:1658)
>     javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:862)
>     org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationExecutor.execute(InvokeApplicationExecutor.java:42)
>     org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:196)
>     org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:143)
>     javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:198)
>     org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:100)
>
> causa raíz
>
> javax.transaction.RollbackException: Unable to commit: transaction
>   marked for rollback
>     org.apache.geronimo.transaction.manager.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:272)
>     org.apache.geronimo.transaction.manager.TransactionManagerImpl.commit(TransactionManagerImpl.java:252)
>     org.apache.openejb.core.transaction.JtaTransactionPolicy.completeTransaction(JtaTransactionPolicy.java:375)
>     org.apache.openejb.core.transaction.TxRequired.commit(TxRequired.java:76)
>     org.apache.openejb.core.transaction.EjbTransactionUtil.afterInvoke(EjbTransactionUtil.java:77)
>     org.apache.openejb.core.stateless.StatelessContainer._invoke(StatelessContainer.java:246)
>     org.apache.openejb.core.stateless.StatelessContainer.invoke(StatelessContainer.java:194)
>     org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.EjbObjectProxyHandler.synchronizedBusinessMethod(EjbObjectProxyHandler.java:317)
>     org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.EjbObjectProxyHandler.businessMethod(EjbObjectProxyHandler.java:312)
>     org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.EjbObjectProxyHandler._invoke(EjbObjectProxyHandler.java:92)
>     org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.BaseEjbProxyHandler.invoke(BaseEjbProxyHandler.java:325)
>     fachadas.UbicacionFacade$$LocalBeanProxy.agregarUbicacion(fachadas/UbicacionFacade.java)
>     porotosAdministrados.UbicacionesBacking.ubicacionNueva(UbicacionesBacking.java:38)
>     sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>     sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
>     org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:279)
>     org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:273)
>     org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.el.ContextAwareTagMethodExpression.invoke(ContextAwareTagMethodExpression.java:96)
>     org.apache.myfaces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:74)
>     javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:120)
>     javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot._broadcastAll(UIViewRoot.java:1172)
>     javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:365)
>     javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot._process(UIViewRoot.java:1658)
>     javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:862)
>     org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationExecutor.execute(InvokeApplicationExecutor.java:42)
>     org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:196)
>     org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:143)
>     javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:198)
>     org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:100)
>
> causa raíz
>
> org.apache.geronimo.transaction.manager.SetRollbackOnlyException:
>   setRollbackOnly() called.  See stacktrace for origin
>     org.apache.geronimo.transaction.manager.TransactionImpl.setRollbackOnly(TransactionImpl.java:126)
>     org.apache.geronimo.transaction.manager.TransactionManagerImpl.setRollbackOnly(TransactionManagerImpl.java:243)
>     org.apache.openejb.core.TransactionSynchronizationRegistryWrapper.setRollbackOnly(TransactionSynchronizationRegistryWrapper.java:72)
>     org.apache.openjpa.ee.RegistryManagedRuntime$TransactionManagerRegistryFacade.setRollbackOnly(RegistryManagedRuntime.java:128)
>     org.apache.openjpa.ee.RegistryManagedRuntime.setRollbackOnly(RegistryManagedRuntime.java:74)
>     org.apache.openjpa.ee.AutomaticManagedRuntime.setRollbackOnly(AutomaticManagedRuntime.java:274)
>     org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.setRollbackOnlyInternal(BrokerImpl.java:1672)
>     org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.setRollbackOnly(BrokerImpl.java:1652)
>     org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingBroker.setRollbackOnly(DelegatingBroker.java:980)
>     org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerImpl.setRollbackOnly(EntityManagerImpl.java:630)
>     org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceExceptions$2.translate(PersistenceExceptions.java:75)
>     org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.translateManagedCompletionException(BrokerImpl.java:2091)
>     org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.beforeCompletion(BrokerImpl.java:2025)
>     org.apache.geronimo.transaction.manager.TransactionImpl.beforeCompletion(TransactionImpl.java:527)
>     org.apache.geronimo.transaction.manager.TransactionImpl.beforeCompletion(TransactionImpl.java:512)
>     org.apache.geronimo.transaction.manager.TransactionImpl.beforePrepare(TransactionImpl.java:413)
>     org.apache.geronimo.transaction.manager.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:262)
>     org.apache.geronimo.transaction.manager.TransactionManagerImpl.commit(TransactionManagerImpl.java:252)
>     org.apache.openejb.core.transaction.JtaTransactionPolicy.completeTransaction(JtaTransactionPolicy.java:375)
>     org.apache.openejb.core.transaction.TxRequired.commit(TxRequired.java:76)
>     org.apache.openejb.core.transaction.EjbTransactionUtil.afterInvoke(EjbTransactionUtil.java:77)
>     org.apache.openejb.core.stateless.StatelessContainer._invoke(StatelessContainer.java:246)
>     org.apache.openejb.core.stateless.StatelessContainer.invoke(StatelessContainer.java:194)
>     org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.EjbObjectProxyHandler.synchronizedBusinessMethod(EjbObjectProxyHandler.java:317)
>     org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.EjbObjectProxyHandler.businessMethod(EjbObjectProxyHandler.java:312)
>     org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.EjbObjectProxyHandler._invoke(EjbObjectProxyHandler.java:92)
>     org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.BaseEjbProxyHandler.invoke(BaseEjbProxyHandler.java:325)
>     fachadas.UbicacionFacade$$LocalBeanProxy.agregarUbicacion(fachadas/UbicacionFacade.java)
>     porotosAdministrados.UbicacionesBacking.ubicacionNueva(UbicacionesBacking.java:38)
>     sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>     sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
>     org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:279)
>     org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:273)
>     org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.el.ContextAwareTagMethodExpression.invoke(ContextAwareTagMethodExpression.java:96)
>     org.apache.myfaces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:74)
>     javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:120)
>     javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot._broadcastAll(UIViewRoot.java:1172)
>     javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:365)
>     javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot._process(UIViewRoot.java:1658)
>     javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:862)
>     org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationExecutor.execute(InvokeApplicationExecutor.java:42)
>     org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:196)
>     org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:143)
>     javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:198)
>     org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:100)
>
> nota La traza completa de la causa de este error se encuentra en los
>   archivos de diario de Apache Tomcat (TomEE)/7.0.68 (1.7.4).

Answer (score 0):

the real error/exception is likely before these lines (JTA stack can just log there was an error but generally JPA logs if there is a constraint/validation/other issue)